# OpenCV C++ 'Access Violation' with SURF

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying using SURF feature detector but I'm always getting this error-

`The program '[1120] Corner Detection.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

Here is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree\nonfree.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void foo(Mat &image1, Mat &image2)
{
 int minHeassian = 400;

 SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHeassian);

 std::vector< KeyPoint > keypoints1, keypoints2;

 keypoints1.resize(1000);
 keypoints2.resize(1000);

 detector.detect(image1, keypoints1);  // <--- crashes at this line
 detector.detect(image2, keypoints2);  // <--- probably will crash here too

 SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

 Mat discriptors1, discriptors2;

 extractor.compute(image1, keypoints1, discriptors1);
 extractor.compute(image2, keypoints2, discriptors2);

 FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

 std::vector< DMatch > matches;

 matcher.match(discriptors1, discriptors2, matches);

 double minDist = 100;

 for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
  if (matches[i].distance < minDist)
   minDist = matches[i].distance;

 std::vector< DMatch > goodMatches;

 for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
  if (matches[i].distance <= max(0.02, (double)matches[i].distance))
   goodMatches.push_back(matches[i]);

 Mat matchImage;

 drawMatches(image1, keypoints1, image2, keypoints2,
  goodMatches, matchImage,
  Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(),
  DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

 namedWindow("Matches", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 imshow("Matches", matchImage);

 waitKey(0);

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 cv::initModule_nonfree();

 Mat left, right;
 right = imread("D:\\right.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
 left = imread("D:\\left.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
 foo(left, right);
 return 0;
}
```

I get the error at the line

`detector.detect(image1, keypoints1);`

I have following lib files mentioned to linker-

```
opencv_core249d.lib
opencv_imgproc249d.lib
opencv_highgui249d.lib
opencv_ml249d.lib
opencv_video249d.lib
opencv_features2d249d.lib
opencv_calib3d249d.lib
opencv_objdetect249d.lib
opencv_contrib249d.lib
opencv_legacy249d.lib
opencv_flann249d.lib
opencv_features2d249.lib
opencv_nonfree249.lib
```

I have tried everything I found on the Internet but nothing worked. What is wrong with this code?

I'm running VS 2013 on Windows 8.1 and I'm using OpenCV version 2.4.9.

**Solved**

It was a silly mistake. I used the library `opencv_nonfree249.lib` whereas I should be using `opencv_nonfree249**d**.lib` as I was working in debug mode.

Comment: What happens if you don't call `resize()` on the keypoints?

Comment: @Doug, the program crashes in the same manner. I just added that line thinking it must be assuming pre allocated vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the library `opencv_nonfree249.lib` in a debug environment which is meant for release environment. Add a `d` to the lib name to make it `opencv_nonfree249d.lib` which will work for debug environment.